# Evaluate Tricky Multivariable Integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, integral-equations

I'm trying to model an experiment for a paper which includes an integral that should be no problem for mathematica but it refuses to integrate it. The integral I need to evaluate is as follows

```
G[q_, t_] := (E^(2 I Sqrt[676000000 \[Pi]^2 -q^2] (23/1000000 + 
(1 - Cos[75000 t])/20000))q^3 ((8.46*^11 + 2.63*^11 I) 
Sqrt[1.88*^-13 - q^2] - Sqrt[(0.16 + 0.049 I) - q^2]))/(Sqrt[
676000000 \[Pi]^2 - q^2] ((8.46*^11 + 2.63*^11 I) Sqrt[1.88*^-13 
- q^2] + Sqrt[(0.15 + 0.049 I) - q^2]));
```

[image]

As you can see, it's a function of both `q` and `t` and I need to integrate it over `q` while keeping `t` constant as I have to integrate over `t` later on in the simulation. I have no idea why it won't integrate, please help!

**Supplementary Information** - *this is me trying to solve the problem*

The function `G` here is made up of two functions, `rp`, and another called `Phi_{PDM}`.

`Phi_{PDM}` integrated over q is no problem, it's also where the `t` dependence comes from, I've included here for completeness.

[image]

The problem lies with the function `rp` as I cannot get mathematica to integrate this function over `q`

[image]

[image]

As you can see, there is a singularity at small values of q which is probably whats causing the problem and I tried to mitigate this with assuming q is real and/or is above 10 but this still does not help. Here is the code for the equations:

```
Phi[q_, t_] := (q^3/(Sqrt[(2*\[Pi]*13000)^2 - q^2]))*Exp[I*2* 
(Sqrt[(2*\[Pi]*13000)^2 - q^2])*(23*^-6 + 50*^-6*(1 - 
Cos[75000*t]))];

rp[q_] := ((8.46*^11 + 2.63*^11 I) Sqrt[1.88*^-13 - q^2] - 
Sqrt[(0.16 + 0.049 I) - q^2])/((8.47*^11 + 2.63`*^11 I) Sqrt[
 1.88*^-13 - q^2] + Sqrt[(0.16 + 0.049 I) - q^2])
```

I'm not very good at mathematica and I'm certainly not the savviest when it comes to mathematics in general so any ideas regarding this, or indeed a method of solving `G` that I'm just not seeing due to me being a novice, would massively appreciate!

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Have you tried `NIntegrate`?

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the welcome. As I said in the post, NIntegrate is useless for my purposes, I must solve it with the Integrate function

Comment: It is not quite understandable: You have to integrate a numerical function und **must** avoid `NIntegrate` ?

Comment: Well I have isolated the problem I'm having later in the code with this expression. For my simulation there is also a time dependent variable "t" included in the integral leaving me with an expression to integrate over "q" while leaving "t" constant. Since I know it's this particular part of of the expression that's giving me trouble, I thought I would simplify but if you think it makes more sense to include the full expression then I shall do so!

Comment: @Koji Please show the full expression. Knowing  `rp[q,t]` you can calculate `int[t_ NumericQ]:=NIntegrate[rp[q,t],{q,0,20}]` depending on `t`.

Comment: Okay working on it! Many apologies for not being clear!

Comment: Okay, I hope the problem is a little clearer now

Comment: `Plot[Im[rp[q]], {q, 1, 20}, PlotRange -> {0, 0.0004}]` works well for me in 13.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: Yes but my problem isn't plotting, it's integrating the function G so I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Integral in `In[2]` in the picture can be integrate like this: ``B = Integrate[
  Rationalize[((8.46`*^11 + 2.63`*^11 I) Sqrt[1.88`*^-13 - q^2] - 
     Sqrt[(0.16` + 0.049` I) - q^2])/((8.47`*^11 + 2.63`*^11 I) Sqrt[
      1.88`*^-13 - q^2] + Sqrt[(0.16` + 0.049` I) - q^2]), 0] // 
   FullSimplify, q]; ANSWER = ((B /. q -> 20) - (B /. q -> 0))`` and `%//N` to get numeric value.

Comment: Oh wow it does! Nice! However when I use this to try and integrate the function G, it doesn't work. Could you perhaps explain why there is a zero at the end of the Rationalize function? Also, what does the code line ANSWER mean? Forgive me, I'm a Mathematica novice

Comment: `Rationalize[x,0]` converts any inexact number x to rational form. For more information execute this     : `?Rationalize`.

Comment: Okay, thanks! This is a good lead!

Comment: If you first `Rationalize` rp[q] via `rpQ[q_]:=Rationalize[rp[q],0]`, then Mathematica can indifinitely integrate it via `Integrate[rpQ[q],q]`.  The antiderivative may however have branch-cuts.  But you can if you wish easily check the antiderivative at the limits to the numerical results via `NIntegrate`.  Might be an interesting exercise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the issue and thought it instructive to post the solution:

A contributor in the comments mentioned using `NumericQ` with `NIntegrate`, a function I had never previously come across. Turn out you can attach this to variable in an equation and it acts as a placeholder until such time that there is a number for that variable that then allows you to solve the problem numerically

```
rp[q_] := ((8.46*^11 + 2.63*^11 I) Sqrt[1.88*^-13 - q^2] - 
Sqrt[(0.16 + 0.049 I) - q^2])/((8.47*^11 + 2.63`*^11 I) Sqrt[
1.88*^-13 - q^2] + Sqrt[(0.16 + 0.049 I) - q^2])

\[Phi][\[Omega]_, q_, t_] := (q^3/(Sqrt[(2*\[Pi]*\[Omega])^2 - q^2]))*
Exp[I*2*(Sqrt[(2*\[Pi]*\[Omega])^2 - q^2])*z[t]];

G[\[Omega]_, t_?NumericQ] := 
NIntegrate[rp[\[Omega], q]*\[Phi][\[Omega], q, t], {q, 0, 2000000}]
array = ConstantArray[0, 50];

For[i = 1, i < 51, i++,
   array[[i]] = NIntegrate[Rationalize[FullSimplify[\[Alpha]tip[[i]]/(
   1 - \[Alpha]tip[[i]]*G[\[Nu][[i]], t])]]*Exp[I*5*75000*t], {q,0, 
   2000000}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]/75000}, AccuracyGoal -> 5];
   ]
```

[image]